# Sitecore Commerce 9.2 Sellable items and Catalogs not indexed

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

I am setting up Sitecore commerce 9.2 environments.

I have created my authoring and shops environment and have added some sample products.

I do not see Category or Sellable items indexed to Solr, but Catalog item gets indexed. What am I missing?

I have updated `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Common.config` and `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config`.

Comment: What have you updated in Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Common.config and Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I updated the environment values to point to my authoring and shops environment.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the wrong shared environments database value set in `Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json`. Indexing is working fine once I set it to the right database.